# evaluate sqrt in text in graphics of python

Tags: python

Because of long codings, I put codings in this link:http://textuploader.com/5xofp

Here is the small codings:

```
from graphics import *
from math import *
def main():
win = GraphWin('Simple Calculator',400,600)
win.setBackground('slategray')
p1 = Point(10,70)
p2 = Point(390,10)
display_box = Rectangle(p1,p2)
display_box.draw(win)
text = Text(Point(190,30),"")
text.setStyle('italic')
text.setSize(15)
text.draw(win)

sqrt = Rectangle(Point(70,190),Point(120,140))
sqrt.draw(win)
sqrt1 = Text(Point(95,165),"√ ")
sqrt1.setStyle('italic')
sqrt1.setSize(36)
sqrt1.draw(win)

eq_sign = Rectangle(Point(170,510),Point(240,440))
eq_sign.draw(win)
eq = Text(Point(205,475),"=")
eq.setStyle('italic')
eq.setSize(36)
eq.draw(win)

num1 = Rectangle(Point(10,270),Point(80,200))
num1.draw(win)
num1_ = Text(Point(45,235),"1")
num1_.setStyle('italic')
num1_.setSize(36)
num1_.draw(win)

if 10<=mouse.x<=80 and 200<=mouse.y<=270:
        text.setText(text.getText()+"1")
if 70<=mouse.x<=120 and 140<=mouse.y<=190:
        text.setText(text.getText()+"sqrt(")
if 170<=mouse.x<=240 and 440<=mouse.y<=510:#=
        try:
            result = eval(text.getText())
        except:
            result = "ERROR"
        text.setText(result)
main（）
```

why when I enters sqrt(36), it gives error in the text? I have already made it as a string.
Is there any mistake in my codings?

Comment: I tried running your code and got `ImportError: No module named graphics`. And it's too long to debug by eye. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: try to put this module in the library http://mcsp.wartburg.edu/zelle/python/graphics/graphics.pdf

Comment: I assume you meant to link to http://mcsp.wartburg.edu/zelle/python/graphics.py, but OK, I'll try it. Thanks :-)

Comment: How are you using non-ASCII characters in the code? For example, this line: ``π = Text(Point(305,395),'π')``? you also have non-ASCII characters for square root, division symbols. Python variable names can only be ASCII characters, and the strings in python2 are ASCII, if you want to use special symbols you'll have to use unicode strings.

Comment: @deepak, Python 3.X [supports the use of some Unicode characters](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers) in variable names. I agree it wouldn't work in 2.7 though.

Comment: @Kevin Ah okay makes sense then. The OP didn't specify the python version so i assumed it was 2.x.

Answer (score 1):

```
sqrt = Rectangle(Point(70,190),Point(120,140))
sqrt.draw(win)
```

This overwrites the math module's `sqrt` function with a Rectangle object. Try changing the name of this variable to something else.

```
sqrt_button = Rectangle(Point(70,190),Point(120,140))
sqrt_button.draw(win)
```